# How to intent ArrayList<ClassObject> from Fragment To Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arraylist

I want to send ArrayList contains getter setter class objects. But I'm facing an error like:

```
The method putParcelableArrayListExtra(String, ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String, ArrayList<BloodDonor>)
```

// Call New Activity

```
ArrayList<BloodDonor> bloodDonors = filterData(selectedCountry, selectedState, selectedCity, selectedZip, selectedbloodgroup);
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DonerListActivity.class);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("bloodDonorList", bloodDonors);
startActivity(intent);
```

// declaration of  `filterData()` method.

```
private ArrayList<BloodDonor> filterData(String SelectedCountry,
        String selectedState, String selectedCity, String selectedZip,
        String bloodgroup) {

    ArrayList<BloodDonor> bloodDonor = new ArrayList<BloodDonor>();

    Log.d("DB", "values in filter" + SelectedCountry + selectedState
            + selectedCity + selectedZip);

    DatabaseHelperDao helperDao = new DatabaseHelperDao(getActivity());
    try {
        helperDao.open();
        bloodDonor = helperDao.fatchDoner(SelectedCountry,
                selectedState, selectedCity, selectedZip, bloodgroup);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getStackTrace();
    } finally {
        helperDao.close();
    }
    return bloodDonor;

}
```

dao method `fetchdonor()` return donors list.
Please Help me here.Thanks

Comment: BloodDonor object should implements Parcelable, more details you can find here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you missed to implements `Parcelable` interface in your `BloodDonor` object.

More information about `Parcelable` you can find [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html).